# Is there a way to manually attach packages and globals with `future.apply::future_apply`

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r-future

I am using R's excellent future package. And in the documentation it mentions `%global%` and `%packages%` for assigning global variables and packages to be evaluated in the future environment. But those seem to only work with `%<-%`.

My question is: is there away to do that with `future_apply` as well. I tried

```r
x = 1
future.apply::future_sapply(1:50, function(y) {
  glue("{x}")
}) %packages% "glue" %globals% "x"
```

and It doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the help page for `future_sapply`, you'll see that `future_lapply` has the arguments `future.packages` and `future.globals`, and if you read carefully, these are also used in `future_sapply`.  So this works:

```
x = 1
future.apply::future_sapply(1:50, function(y) {
  glue("{x}")
}, future.packages = "glue", future.globals = "x")
```